# How to use same object from main activity in service

Tags: android

I want to use ArrayAdapter and MediaRouter objects in Service from my main Activity. what is the best solution for it?

```
  public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    MediaRouter router;
    ArrayAdapter<RouteInfoWrapper> adapter;
    ListView list;

    MediaRouter.Callback callback = new MediaRouter.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onRouteAdded(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteAdded(router, route);
            if (route.isDefault())
                return;
            adapter.add(new RouteInfoWrapper(route));
        }
    };

    public static class RouteInfoWrapper {
        MediaRouter.RouteInfo routeInfo;
        public RouteInfoWrapper(MediaRouter.RouteInfo routeInfo) {
            this.routeInfo = routeInfo;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return routeInfo.getName();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RouteInfoWrapper>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, android.R.id.text1);
        router = MediaRouter.getInstance(this);
        for (MediaRouter.RouteInfo route: router.getRoutes()) {
            if (route.isDefault())
                continue;
            adapter.add(new RouteInfoWrapper(route));
```

I want to share the adapter, callback and router object to service.

Comment: Still not clear. Do you want to access ArrayAdapter inside Service/ If yes then why? Does not make much sense

Comment: I would advice against directly passing callback, router and adapter to service class. Best way would be create an interface between activity and service. Implement it in activity and pass that to service during binding. In service by calling the interface you can perform necessary action.

Comment: yes i want to access arrayAdapter in service to access the element stored in arrayadapter while main activity's oncreate

Comment: thank you @shadow droid for your answer. i am new in android developement so if you have any example related to your answer then plz share it with me

Comment: this should help https://medium.com/@ankit_aggarwal/ways-to-communicate-between-activity-and-service-6a8f07275297 Kindly understand examples provided here and implement things in your way.